# react UseEffect with a dynmac setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to have a dynamic setInterval in a useEffect react hook because I don't want to have calls each x seconds.
As I'm working on live videos and end date can change during the time I add a little method "onAirRequestInterval" to query the API with a dynamic interval as mentionned below :

```
const onAirRequestInterval = () => {
    const programEndDate = new Date(program?.endTime).getTime();
    const currentDate = Date.now();
    const airRequestInterval = (programEndDate - currentDate) / 2;
    return airRequestInterval > 60000 ? airRequestInterval : 30000;
};

useEffect(() => {
    let interval;
    if (program?.status === ONAIR) {

      interval = setInterval(() => {
        fetchQuery(
          environment,
          onAirProgramsQuery,
          { channelId: program?.channel?.id }, // 'Y2hhbm5lbDpldXJvc3BvcnQtMjAz'
          { force: true }
        ).then(fragmentData => {
          setOnAirProgramsfragmentData(fragmentData);
        });
      }, onAirRequestInterval);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [environment, onAirProgramsQuery, program]);
```

But I get errors in the console, doesn't seem to work.

Anybody can help me on this please?

Thanks

Comment: You should add the errors in your question

Comment: you're passing the `onAirRequestInterval` function to setInverval, it should be `onAirRequestInterval()`. Also, the function should be defined inside the useEffect call